# How i use swiper js with npm (vanila javascript)

Tags: npm, node-modules, swiper.js

I am facing several problems using swiper js when i Initialize it with npm

Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/css". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.